Getting unusual tensor strides in backwards pass when using Pytorch’s custom autograd feature
I'm getting strides like (0, 0) when writing custom Pytorch autograd functions. Here's a minimal, reproducible example:
import torch

class Identity(torch.autograd.Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, input):
        return input

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        print(grad_output.shape, grad_output.stride())
        return grad_output

# Create a callable object for the Identity function
identity = Identity.apply


# Example usage
x = torch.randn(3, 3, requires_grad=True)
y = identity(x)
z = y.sum()
z.backward()

print(x.grad)  # Should be a 3x3 tensor of ones

This is causing problems / leading to incorrect results when using more complicated autograd functions where I try to make grad_output contiguous.
What is causing this issue / how can I fix it?

I believe this is due to pytorch taking a view of the scalar gradient value to avoid excess memory writes. The gradient tensor is a (3,3) tensor, but each entry in the tensor holds the same value, so pytorch instead allocates a single value and takes a (3,3) view of it. For example:
# create (1,1) tensor with (1,1) stride
x = torch.tensor([[1]])
print(x.stride())
> (1, 1)

# create view with expand, new tensor now has (0,0) stride
x_view = x.expand(3,3)
print(x_view.stride())
> (0, 0)

You can avoid the view by backproping from a non-aggregated tensor:
import torch

class Identity(torch.autograd.Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, input):
        return input

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        print(grad_output.shape, grad_output.stride())
        return grad_output

identity = Identity.apply

x = torch.ones(3, 3, requires_grad=True)
y = identity(x)
y.backward(gradient=torch.ones_like(y)) # backprop directly from y
> torch.Size([3, 3]) (3, 1)

print(x.grad)
> tensor([[1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [1., 1., 1.]])

